# Add two fields together

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code with two fields, but I need the first and second math calculation in the same field, but when I used if, only the first still making the multiplication and division won't work in the second field:

field 1:

```
      {
    field: ["volumeWater", "volumeBasc"],
    updates: (
      value,
      name,
      { volumeWater, volumeBasc}
    ) => {
      const changes= {};

      if (volumeBasc&& volumeWater) {
        const qtdBascAwait = (
          volumeWater/ volumeBasc
        ).toFixed(1);
        changes["volumeWaterMeasure"] = (
          volumeWater* 0.025
        ).toPrecision(8);
        
      }
      return changes;
    },
  },
```

And this is the second field:

```
     {
    field: [
     
      "volumeWaterMeasure",
    ],
    updates: (value, name, {  volumeBasc, volumeWaterMeasure}
      ) => {
      const mudancas = {};

      if (volumeWaterMeasure && volumeBasc) {
       //  const erro = (
       //    volumeWaterMeasure/ volumeBasc
       //  ).toFixed(1);
        
        changes["volumeWater"] = (
          volumeWaterMeasure/ 0.025
        ).toPrecision(8);

      }

      return changes;
    },
  },
```

0

I need the the first and secound math calculation in the same field, but when I used if, only the first still making the multiplication and division won't work in the secound field

Comment: put them together in the sense???, can you explain your requirement

Comment: Can you show what is your expected result ?

Comment: if the effect you want to use is to make one value dependent on another value than use useEffect with dependencies.